# Change Datarow field value

Tags: c#, excel, datarow

First I have last update file from DB

```
DataTable excelData = ReadSCOOmega(lastUploadFile);
```

, after this iterate over this data

```
foreach (DataRow currentRow in rows)
{
     currentRow.
}
```

Is that possible to change da data in the foreach loop.I can **access only** the value of this data

```
currentRow.Field<object>("Some column name")
```

but not to change it.My idea is selected.I have a multiple deals in excel file and when is upload to DB, I need to make changes in this file.Is that possible or I need to store the data in other collection?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use indexer to set the data stored to the field: `currentRow["columnName"] = value`.

See [MSDN DataRow.Item Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 19):

You can do that like :

```
foreach (DataRow currentRow in excelData.Rows)
{
    currentRow.BeginEdit();
    currentRow["ColumnName"] = value;
    //.....
    currentRow.EndEdit();
}
```